# При возврате на страницу через "кнопку назад" не срабатывает jQuerymenu.addClass

Tags: jquery

В jQuery не силён совершенно, и не знаю, что именно гуглить, чтобы решить проблему. На сайте есть код, который добавляет к верхней менюшку новый класс и тем самым меняет её стиль. (была прозрачной, стала с цветом.)

Есть момент, что если нажать в браузере кнопку "назад", то человек возвращается на на прошлую страницу на тот момент, когда стиль из скрипта должен быть уже добавлен, но он не добавлен. Добавляет только при малейшей прокрутке.

Вопрос такой - как сделать или хотя бы через что гуглить, чтобы стиль "подвешивался" подинамичней что ли)) Извините за сумбур.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var jQuerymenu = jQuery("#menu");
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 50 && !jQuerymenu.hasClass("headermenuwrap") ){
        jQuerymenu.addClass("headermenuwrap");
    } else 
    if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= 50 && jQuerymenu.hasClass("headermenuwrap")) {
        jQuerymenu.removeClass("headermenuwrap");
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var jQuerymenu = jQuery("#menu");
  jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    ... 
  });
  jQuery(window).scroll();
});
```

Comment: Игорь, Вы мой спаситель. Вы круты. Благодарю. :)